# Objects disappearing in animation render

Tags: rendering, objects, visibility

I made a short animation with the camera following a path in between some floating objects (zooming in effect)

When I go to render, the objects disappear whilst they should still be in view of the camera as it moves closer.

If I change the clip start to 0.01, the same thing happens. If I change the clip start to 0.001 they still disappear and the topology of my objects looks really corrupted and bad.

I have tried resizing my entire scene bigger and also smaller, I have tried increasing the size of my objects and positioning them furthur away from the camera. I have tried making the path longer, therefore pushing my camera away and increasing the focal length, but none of these solutions make my objects visible for the whole shot.

Any other suggestions on how to fix this would be great!

[image: I can see the objects for the whole duration of the animation when in rendered viewport mode]

[image: They disappear in the actual render]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: It's possible your camera is too close to your objects origins, thus excluding them from view when the camera clipping is zoomed in.

Comment: @Chris Here's a link to the blend file https://we.tl/t-BHKUSYX6IW

Comment: weird. i have no idea why this happens. sorry.